# Why my status bar is not keeping existing color?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

[image]
[image]

**I was added this line of code in Main Activity, i'm using single activity architecuture**

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
  val windows = (LocalView.current.parent as? DialogWindowProvider)?.window
                    ?: LocalView.current.context.findWindow()
                if (windows != null) {
                    windows.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
                    windows.statusBarColor = android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT


}
```

**and put this code in my LoginScreen**

```
val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()

DisposableEffect(Unit) {
    systemUiController.isNavigationBarVisible = true
    systemUiController.setNavigationBarColor(MilkWhite)
    systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(Color.Transparent,true)

    onDispose {
        systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(Color.Transparent,true)

    }
}
```

When i navigate in other screen, and back again in previous (LoginScreen) the fullscreen image is change into White status bar,

I Triger with this code

```
navController.navigate(ChildScreen.Login.route)
```

Comment: Why are you using DisposableEffect for this?

Comment: i follow someone in medium

Comment: Do you want the color of the status bar to be transparent for the whole application or just the LoginScreen?

Comment: @tomerpacific yes just for specifics screen

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code you shared above, you are using a library from [Accompanist](https://google.github.io/accompanist/systemuicontroller/). This library enables you to get the `systemUiController`.

In their documentation, you can see the following snippet:

```
// Remember a SystemUiController
val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
val useDarkIcons = !isSystemInDarkTheme()

DisposableEffect(systemUiController, useDarkIcons) {
    // Update all of the system bar colors to be transparent, and use
    // dark icons if we're in light theme
    systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(
        color = Color.Transparent,
        darkIcons = useDarkIcons
    )

    // setStatusBarColor() and setNavigationBarColor() also exist

    onDispose {}
}
```

Your DisposableEffect's argument is Unit, so I can suggest to alter your code to this:

```
val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()

DisposableEffect(systemUiController) {
    systemUiController.isNavigationBarVisible = true
    systemUiController.setNavigationBarColor(MilkWhite)
    systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(Color.Transparent,true)

    onDispose {
        systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(Color.Transparent,true)

    }
}
```

**Notice that this library is no longer maintained.**

> This library is deprecated, and the API is no longer maintained. We
> recommend forking the implementation and customising it to your needs.

Comment: I was implemented your code, but still didn't work after navigate back to LoginScreen. Thanks for your answer, i fully appreciate